# process simultaneously using batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-processing, simultaneous

i want to do processing for different file simultaneously in batch file
the command i use is

> for %%f in (AXUD*,DSET*,APEC*) do teqc +qc %%f

But from my observation, the program process one by one file, AXUD first, then after finish it process DSET file

how can i make it process all 3 file simultaneously at same time.

hope can help

than you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for %%f in (AXUD*,DSET*,APEC*) do (
  START teqc +qc %%f
)
```

may be this way?

Answer (score 1):

You need to start each file in background mode, that can be done using the /B parameter of start command

PS: No need to separate the expressions using **,** or **;**

```
@Echo OFF

:: By Elektro H@cker

For %%# in (AXUD* DSET* APEC*) DO (
    START /B teqc +qc %%#

    REM If you have files with space in filenames then you better try to use this:
    REM START /D /B "C:\Full path to teqc\" teqc.exe +qc "%%#"
)

Pause&Exit
```